# Server CPU too high

Tags: cpu-usage

Recently I have to restart my server because it was not responding. I'm looking at the logs but I can't find anything valuable to know which the error was.

The droplet CPU was 100% for hours. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

When the droplet was having problems the site wasn't avaible and neither the shell access.

I don't know what else can I do to find the error or it's possible causes. Where should I start looking? What specific logs could be more useful here?

Now everything is fine, after the restart... but it could happen again.

Help me please. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Before messing with Nagios and the likes, I suggest you to install `sar` to keep your server monitored. It basically require no configuration but at the same time it collects many key stats about what is running/happening on your server.

Comment: THanks @shodanshok, I will look for "sar". It's interesting to have program to monitor the performance and log about details that are not always easy to find in the logs. I will try it. Until the server is still working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Well first and foremost, do you have any monitoring tools such as [Nagios](https://www.nagios.org/), to highlight you in real time of these events? This would be a good suggestion for you to configure to monitor your server, it can do a number of SNMP commands such as:

[Service Monitoring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3B3sT.jpg)

[Event Handling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9suX.jpg)

[Multiple Host Monitoring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5Bky.jpg)

For more details, look at the following add-on [here](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/System-Metrics/Processes/Check-Any-Process-on-Windows-and-Linux-Systems/details):

```
======= 
USAGE: 
======= 

./checkProcessesviaSNMP.sh <community-string> <remote-host> <process-names> <warning> <critical> <type>
```

This tool should be able to monitor a number of real-time events on your server and alert you via E-Mail (given you configure SMTP).

This solution will not stop the fault, but should give you real-time alert as to what is happening.

Comment: When the droplet was with having the issue was impossible to login through SSH, I would use "top" also for monitor, but the server was almost inoperable.

Comment: @BetoAveiga Beto, I doubt there is anything you can do in that situation. If you monitor in real time (and collect the logs) potentially you can solve the issue before it occurs again.